# Problemas jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um problema que é o seguinte:

no meu sistema tenho um combo que serve de parametro para carregar( via ajax) um segundo combo, isso funciona normalmente.

Daí preciso que ao clicar num item de uma tabela, o primeiro combo seja atualizado e com base no item selecionado do combo ele carregue um segundo combo.

Mas não funciona!

já usei on / live / bind do jquery, mas não funciona

### segue o código:

$('.tableLineCargo').live('click', preencherFormularioCargo);
$('#responsavelcombo').on('change', listarAlvos);

```
    function listarAlvos(){
      var dados = {
        acao: 'combo',
        nome: alvo
      };

      var vurl;
      var respcombo = $('#responsavelcombo').val();

      if (respcombo == 0){
        $('#alvocombo').html("");
      }else{
        if (respcombo == 1){vurl = 'associacaocrud.php';}
        if (respcombo == 2){vurl = 'grupocrud.php';}
        if (respcombo == 3){vurl = 'regiaocrud.php';}
        if (respcombo == 4){vurl = 'templocrud.php';}

        $.ajax({
          url: vurl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: dados,
          success: function(retorno){
            $('#alvocombo').html(retorno);           
          }
        });
      }
    };
```

Comment: Acredito que para alguém lhe ajudar, será necessária as informações relevantes.

Comment: Olá Ney! Clica em [edit] e junta o código que tens para podermos ajuda mais.

Comment: Poste o código do html e do php que você está utilizando com esse ajax, que assim podemos te ajudar melhor.